# Weak convergence and lim inf and lim sup of the sequence of norms

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Assume $x_n$ is a sequence in a Banach space that converges weakly to $x$. Then we know that $\|x\| \leq \lim \inf \|x_n\|$.

1)But can we say that $\lim \inf \|x_n\| < \infty$ or is this in general wrong?

2) In a Hilbert space $X$ if $x_n$ converges weakly to $x$, then we know that
$\lim \sup \|x_n\| \leq \|x\|$ iff $x_n$ converges to $x$ (in norm). But in general i guess it can be that $\lim \sup \|x_n\| = \infty$, right?

Maybe you could give me some illuminating basic examples to illustrate these matters? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It follows from the uniform boundedness principle that any weakly convergent sequence is norm bounded, i.e. $$\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|x_n\|< \infty.$$
2. As already mentioned, it holds that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|x_n\|<\infty$ for any weakly convergent sequence. This implies in particular $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \|x_n\|<\infty.$$

Comment: Thank you. Ad 2) What i wanted to aks was if infinity could occur in the case of a Banach space.

Comment: @Mekanik What do you mean "in case of a Banach space"? The norm $\|x\|$ of any element $x \in X$ in a normed space is finite.

Comment: The inequality $\lim \sup \|x_n\| \leq \|x\|$ in general does not hold if $x_n$ only converges weakly to $x$ (and not in norm), i thought.

Comment: @Mekanik Ah, I see, I misunderstood your question. I thought you *assumed* $x_n \to x$ (in norm) in the second part. However, as I stated in the first part of my answer, it holds that $\sup_n \|x_n\|<\infty$ for any weakly convergent sequence and therefore also $$\limsup_n \|x_n\|<\infty$$ for any weakly convergent subsequence.